# What does ”this reflects their relatively late date” mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I’m translating a text about Safavid carpets and I have problem with understanding this sentence:

> some thousand carpets survive from Safavid period. In part, of course, **this reflects their relatively late date**, but...

Comment: These carpets have survived partly because they are relatively recent - compared to older carpets that have perished or disappeared.

Comment: Are you asking about the meaning of "reflect" in this context? Have you checked a dictionary?